# Parse time format "2015-07-14T09:00:00:+08:000" return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, datetime, time

I try to parse the time but it keeps returning nil. Is there anything I have missed?

```
 var datetime =  "2015-07-14T09:00:00:+08:000"
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:Z"
    if let date : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(datetime){
        var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        let timeString = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        xValues.addObject(timeString)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+08:000` is wrong Timezone specification date format. It should be `+08:00` only, e.g. 8hrs 0min